# Setting style property on table formed with PHP not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, styles

I have a several tables delivered via PHP loop to my page.  At the end of each PHP loop an if statement is run (which is evaluating true) like this:

```
if ($ssstatus[0] == 'F'){

    echo "<script>";
    //echo "alert('We are in this loop');";
    echo "flagfinished(".$gameID.");";
    echo "</script>";

}
```

My flagfinished function is this:

```
function flagfinished(tableid){
//alert("Made it to the function!");
var myid = "table"+tableid;
//alert(myid);

var testel = document.getElementById(myid);
testel.setAttribute("border-style","solid");
};
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working.  I can say that my id attribute on the table is properly set and matches the variable myid.  I've even tried just putting in the text of a single id attribute instead of myid and still no luck.  I've also manually added the "border-style" attribute to my css and it works.  Maybe I am going about this in the wrong way entirely.  Or maybe I am overlooking something obvious.  I've been working on this for hours!  Thanks for any ideas or help!

Comment: what values are in `$gameID`, and did you check what value is in `myid` in the JS code? are you sure you've got elements of that ID in your document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
testel.style.borderStyle = "solid";
```

Comment: That did it, thanks.  Is there a reference somewhere of the available properties I can use here?  For example, how can I find that borderStyle did what border-style does?

Comment: Sure. You'll want to use the style object for these sort of CSS changes using pure JS. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp

Answer (score 0):

The `border-style` that you are trying to define is not an element attribute. The attribute would be `style`. And `border-style` would be a value of the style attribute.

So, in your line of thinking:

```
var testel = document.getElementById(myid);
testel.setAttribute("style", "border-style: solid");
```

But, Javascript DOM already takes care of the style attribute for you, so you can go:

```
var testel = document.getElementById(myid);
testel.style.bordeStyle = "solid";
```

Follows [**MDN HtmlElement.style docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style)

Answer (score 0):

Why are u trying to call flagFinished with javascript anyway? You could do the same with php. Add a css class to the table before sending it to the browser ( echoing / printing out ) and then let css do it's magic? Then you wouldn't have to send all these extra  tags to client, which makes the page load faster, and would be a better solution to use.

you could do something like:

```
<?php
$tables = [
    ['data'   => [
        ['id' => 1, 'content' => 'sample content'],
        ['id' => 2, 'content' => 'sample content jabadabaduuu...'],
        ['id' => 3, 'content' => 'test 1123123123'],
        ['id' => 4, 'content' => 'sample content']
    ],
     'status' => 'F'
    ],
    ['data'   => [
        ['id' => 1, 'content' => 'sample content'],
        ['id' => 2, 'content' => 'sample content jabadabaduuu...'],
        ['id' => 3, 'content' => 'test 1123123123'],
        ['id' => 4, 'content' => 'sample content']
    ],
     'status' => 'S'
    ],
    ['data'   => [
        ['id' => 1, 'content' => 'sample content'],
        ['id' => 2, 'content' => 'sample content jabadabaduuu...'],
        ['id' => 3, 'content' => 'test 1123123123'],
        ['id' => 4, 'content' => 'sample content']
    ],
     'status' => 'F'
    ]
];


foreach ($tables as $table) {
    ?>
    <table id="<?= myUniqueTableIdGeneratorFunction() ?>"
           class="<?= ($table['status']) == 'F' ? 'class-with-border' : null ?>" ><?php
    foreach ($table['data'] as $row) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $row['id'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['content'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?></table><?php
}
?>
```

I havent test this, just wrote this from the top of my head quickly.

Comment: I'm sure this is a wonderful solution.  I think it is a bit overkill for what I am trying to do.  I need some client-side processing hence the need to call a JavaScript function.  I don't want all of that executing on the server.  Thank you for the idea, though!

Comment: Well, tbh ive seen many different implementations for the same kind problems. This is probably one of the simple ways to implement it. Ofcourse you would have much server-sided computation done. But in the other hand, you will load ur page faster, and clients will end up with a better and smoother experience :) just a note :P